# Can You Verify the Health of an Offline MySQL Database Before Starting Services During a Version Upgrade?

Tags: mysql

Our product has MySQL embedded within it which is deployed by our installer.  During upgrades of our software the version of MySQL may be updated as well.  Recently we had a defect in our stack where MySQL did not get shut down properly when our services were stopped.  As a result mysqld could get forcefully terminated during the upgrade.  This can and did lead to tables needing recovery in the middle of a version upgrade.

As a result we had an upgrade go really bad.  The new mysqld (8.x) was started up using the database files from 5.x.  The tables needed some level of repair which the 8.x daemon attempted to do, but failed.  At that point the database would not start at all under 8.x.  We tried to revert back to 5.x but due to changes made by mysqld 8.x, mysqld 5.x would not start either.  Essentially it seemed the database files were corrupted by being 5.x files half (and failed to be) recovered by 8.x.  We ended up having to do a very major restore from dumps and binlogs to recover.

My question is this:

Is there a way to pre-verify the health of the database files on disk before attempting to start mysqld or can mysqld be configured to not attempt to recover tables if recovery is needed and just terminate with an error?

Procedurally we can avoid this during the upgrade process but we would like to find a way to have the installer detect an unhealthy database and abort before attempting to upgrade.  We use NSIS where the uninstaller has already been deployed as part of the last version installation so it is difficult to modify the uninstall process that happens first during the upgrade.

Thanks in advance for any tips or ideas!

Comment: Don't use MyISAM for your tables; use InnoDB.  Then the "recovery" process is relatively painless.

Comment: We already do use all InnoDB tables, but it definitely got into a state we could not figure out how to recover.  Perhaps there was a recovery method I am not aware of ... I did not save the error messages I was getting but it was something similar to data cannot be recovered because it is from a newer version.  The newer version was failing to recover as well...

Comment: You _must_ go through 5.7 to get to 8.0.  Were you trying to go from an older 5.x?

Comment: We were migrating from 5.7.22 to 8.0.15.